# password must contain numbers

Tags: kotlin, passwords, registration

So I'm building registration page type of thing in android studio kotlin and in it password length has to be over 8  symbols and it must contain at least one number otherwise it should not let me press register button

I managed to make it so that jts necessary for password lenght to be over 8 symbols but I cant seem to add the requirement of it containing number. I have tried to use contain(Int) but it gives me an error. I'd greatly appreciate the help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show the code that didn't work so we can correct it.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it is easy to do this in Kotlin. Only we use contains("[0-9]".toRegex()), if there is no number in the password, it returns false and the condition is not fulfilled

Example

```
   if (password.contains("[0-9]".toRegex())) {
       //Write code here
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the `kotlin.text` package with all the standard library stuff for working with text: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/

There's nothing like `contains(Int)` in there, because it would be impossible to have a function where you pass *any type* and it somehow works out if the text *"represents"* an instance of that type somehow, right? Like how would `contains(Bitmap)` or `contains(Dog)` work?

So generally for this kind of thing, you have *specialised functions* that check for a *specific type* - no passing a type in as a parameter. For text, they're often called `parse*`, like `parseInt`. In Kotlin, the standard functions start with `to*` - in this case, `toInt` and `toIntOrNull`. They attempt to parse the string as an integer, and return that `Int` - if it can't be parsed as one, `toInt` throws an exception, `toIntOrNull` returns null instead. (There are other convert-to-number functions too, like `toFloat`)

Now you have a way to check if something is a number or not - call `toIntOrNull()` on it, and see if you get *null* (not a number). And you want to know if *any* of the characters in your string is a number, right? So you can do this:

```
val hasDigit = password.any { it.toIntOrNull() != null }
```

And if that's true for *any* of the characters, the result will be *true*. You could make it an extension function if you like:

```
val String.hasDigit get() = any { it.toIntOrNull() != null }

"password1".hasDigit
>> true
```

---

That's the general way of doing things. In the case of digits specifically, there's a nice [`isDigit()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/is-digit.html) function on `Char`s you can use instead:

```
password.any { it.isDigit() }
// or if you like
password.any(Char::isDigit)
```

and of course you can use other standard functions like `count` if you want a minimum number of digits, etc.

Another thing you can do is create a lookup, and check if characters are in that:

```
// you can use a string
val allowed = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!?*"
// or a list - lots of ways to build it!
val allowed = ('a'..'z') + listOf('!', '?') + '*'

// then check
password.all { it in allowed }
```

or [*Xayal's* regex example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74364193/13598222) - and then you can use `any`, `all`, `none` etc to lay down your rules. Once you're familiar with the standard library, you can combine all these functions to make more specific stuff - that's kinda the way it's designed